# In asp.net how to validate textbox depending on other text box?

Tags: c#, asp.net

In asp.net Depending on Experience I should validate the salary of an employee.

If the employee is fresher his salary should be 1 lac to 1.5 lac. Or salary = 1.5 lac * years of exp to 3.5 * years of exp.

** i have tried his**********
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

```
    if (IntExp == 0)
    {
        RangeValidator1.MaximumValue = "150000";
        RangeValidator1.MinimumValue = "100000";

        RangeValidator1.Type = ValidationDataType.Integer;
        RangeValidator1.Validate();
        if (!RangeValidator1.IsValid)
        {
            RangeValidator1.ErrorMessage = "Enter CTC between 100000 and 150000";
        }
        Response.Redirect("ABCAddEmp.aspx");

    }
    else
    {
        int max = IntExp * 150000;
        int min = IntExp * 350000;
        RangeValidator1.MaximumValue = "max";
        RangeValidator1.MinimumValue = "min";
        RangeValidator1.Type = ValidationDataType.Integer;
        RangeValidator1.Validate();

        if (!RangeValidator1.IsValid)
        {
            RangeValidator1.ErrorMessage = "Enter CTC between " + max + " and " + min;
        }
        Response.Redirect("ABCAddEmp.aspx");
    }
```

Comment: Please provide the code that you tried

Comment: Try `RangeValidator1.MaximumValue = max; RangeValidator1.MinimumValue = min;` (i.e., get rid of the quotes - you're trying to assign a string when it should be an int).  And call ToString() on `max` and `min` in the RangeValidator1.ErrorMessage (or use String.Format()).

Comment: Given the errors noted above in my comment I have to ask - does the posted code even compile?  I don't see how it would...

Answer (score 3):

You are looking to implement a custom validator.  When you place the custom validator on the page, your controlToValidate will be the salary.  Then you need to define your ServerValidate event.  In this event you can validate the employee input based on whether fresher or experienced .  Good luck.